# Angular custom validator always returns null

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a form where the administrator can create a new user. I would like to validate the username field is unique. I have create a uniqueUserNameValidator however this function always returns null. I belive this happens beacouse the service is a async method. I need the result of the async before continuing I have tried to add a await bad this also creates weird problem. How can I fix this issues thank you for your help.

Here is where I want to use the validator

```js
this.userService.getEmployeeById(this.employeeId).subscribe(result => {
        this.employee = result;
        this.employeeDetailForm = new FormGroup({
          userName: new FormControl(this.employee.userName, [Validators.required, this.uniqueUserNameValidator.bind(this)]) 
        });
```

Here is my validator

```js
      private uniqueUserNameValidator(control: FormControl): { [s: string]: boolean } {
    
        this.employee.userName = control.value;
        var userExists: boolean;
    
        this.userService.checkIfEmployeeUserNameExists(this.employee).subscribe(data => {
          userExists = data;
        })
    
        if (userExists) {
          return { userExists: true };
        }
        return null;
      }
```

Here is the service in question

```js
      checkIfEmployeeUserNameExists(employee: Employee) {
        return this.http.put<boolean>(this.baseUrl + 'employees/isUserNameUnique', employee)
      }
```

Comment: @Drenai yes I have but they don't have the service I have where I have to subscribe and wait for a result. Can you show me how to do it with my code please. I have tried the async validators many time they work but not with my service. I don't understand how to do it that is why I am asking on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other users already pointed out in the comments, you should use an async validator to get the behavior that you want. When creating a new control, you can pass in `validatorOrOpts` as the second parameter. This allows you a finer control over the validators that you can set.

```
this.employeeDetailForm = new FormGroup({
  userName: new FormControl(this.employee.userName, {
    validators: [Validators.required],
    asyncValidators: [this.partnerCodeAvailabilityValidator.bind(this)]
  }) 
});
```

The `partnerCodeAvailabilityValidator` should look like this:

```
private partnerCodeAvailabilityValidator(
  control: AbstractControl
): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
  this.employee.userName = control.value;
  return this.userService
    .checkIfEmployeeUserNameExists(this.employee)
    .pipe(map((data) => data ? ({ userExists: data }) : null));
}
```

Alternatively, you could build a directive and implement the `AsyncValidator` interface in case you want to use it with template driven forms.

Comment: I still have one more problem with your solution when the user does not exists   {"userExists": false} this is no problem for the validation of the field username itself however for the button submit this is a issue since the hole form has to be valid  How can I fix this. Basically I want the method to return null when   {"userExists": false} . Thank you

Comment: I added a check in the answer, it will now return null whenever `data` is false, and the `{"userExists": true}` when you should show the error.

Comment: An async validator not implementing the `AsyncValidator` interface... why?

Comment: @paradise It conforms to the [async validator function interface](https://v13.angular.io/api/forms/AsyncValidatorFn).